# Test methods with Junit with mock

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have these two methods that I'm having trouble implementing tests using Mock. How should I take the test?

I'm having trouble getting the Jboss directory without having to start
System.getProperty ("jboss.server.temp.dir");

```
public ResourceRenderer getImagem(String path) throws IOException {

        String resourceLocation = this.getResoureLocation(path);

        InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(caminhoImagemClasspath);
        File file = new File(resourceLocation);
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(resourceAsStream, file);
        return ResourceRenderer.getInstance(file.getAbsolutePath(), false);
    }

public String getResoureLocation(String path) {
    String dirJboss= System.getProperty("jboss.server.temp.dir");
    if (dirJboss != null) {
        return dirJboss + File.separator + caminhoImagemClasspath;
    }
    return System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Mocks, you can extract the calls to System Properties into their own methods and mock those methods' return value.

You could also use System.setProperty and set the values to what you need.

But if I understand correctly, you are trying to test getResourceLocation? In that case, you wouldn't want to test the properties, but rather set them to something and test the logic of your method, which is 1) the String concatenation in the last line and 2) the behaviour if dirJboss is available.

Comment: I can't get the Jboss directory. The test does not start Jboss how do I recover this temporary Jboss directory?